# Is every group having infinitely many element orders a torsion group?

Tags: group-theory

Let (H, ·) be a group having *infinitely many* element orders. 'Element order' denotes any ʞ ∊ ℕ⁺+{∞} such that in H ord(x)=ʞ for some x∊H.

Is H a torsion group ? Or can H actually have an element x such that ord(x)=∞ ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because you can just take a combination. For instance $\Bbb Z\oplus(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ has torsionless terms and also elements of any given order.

Comment: Yep, I thought so. Or take ℤ₀⊕ℤ₂⊕ℤ₃… The set of all element orders of a group G should have a name, such as exponent of G has a name. Do you happen to know an established name ?

Comment: @Peterש sorry, I don't know such a name